# How can I change the Read/Write Permissions of /mnt/SDcard folder on Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, in-app, kindle-fire

I am trying to develop Amazon In-app in android. For this i download the sample code for from this site https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/sample-code/button-clicker.html. This article suggests that we have to put a file amazon.sdktester.json in mnt/sdkcard folder of device. For this i read article from this site https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/connect-adb.html#InstallApp and do the same. But when I tried to push file on sdcard, the eclipse gives me following error:

```
[2012-11-19 13:39:39 - ddms] transfer error: Permission denied

[2012-11-19 13:39:39] Failed to push selection: Permission denied
```

[image]

Is there any way to change the permissions of root folder of Kindle Fire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to use [chmod](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/chmod-command-examples/) command in the [ADB shell](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#shellcommands)...

Following are some chmod sample:

> 1. Add single permission to a file/directory
>
> Changing permission to a single set. + symbol means adding permission.
>   For example, do the following to give execute permission for the user
>   irrespective of anything else:
>
> ```
> $ chmod u+x filename
> ```
>
> 2. Add multiple permission to a file/directory
>
> Use comma to separate the multiple permission sets as shown below.
>
> > $ chmod u+r,g+x filename
>
> 3. Remove permission from a file/directory
>
> Following example removes read and write permission for the user.
>
> > $ chmod u-rx filename
>
> 4. Change permission for all roles on a file/directory
>
> Following example assigns execute privilege to user, group and others
>   (basically anybody can execute this file).
>
> > $ chmod a+x filename
>
> 5. Make permission for a file same as another file (using reference)
>
> If you want to change a file permission same as another file, use the
>   reference option as shown below. In this example, file2′s permission
>   will be set exactly same as file1′s permission.
>
> > $ chmod --reference=file1 file2
>
> 6. Apply the permission to all the files under a directory recursively
>
> Use option -R to change the permission recursively as shown below.
>
> > $ chmod -R 755 directory-name/
>
> 7. Change execute permission only on the directories (files are not affected)
>
> On a particular directory if you have multiple sub-directories and
>   files, the following command will assign execute permission only to
>   all the sub-directories in the current directory (not the files in the
>   current directory).
>
> > $ chmod u+X *